# XSLT 2.0 Combine all values from the element with same name

Tags: xml, xslt

my xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
<credit>
    <CharacterString> Credit 1</CharacterString>
</credit>
<credit>
    <CharacterString> Credit 2</CharacterString>
</credit>
</data>
```

My xslt (2.0) generates two 'description' elements for each 'credit':

```
 <xsl:template match="credit">
        <xsl:if test="string-length(normalize-space(.)) > 0">
            <description type="notes">
                   <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
            </description>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

How can I combine the value of Credit 1 and Credit 2 into one ?

```
<description type="notes"> Credit 1, Credit 2 </description>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="/data">
    <description type="notes">
        <xsl:value-of select="credit/CharacterString" separator=","/> 
    </description>
</xsl:template>
```

If (as it seems) you want to exclude whitespace-only values, use:

```
         <xsl:value-of select="credit/CharacterString[normalize-space()]" separator=","/>
```